# Get the first of each label to append

Tags: jquery, each

I have some class "info" created dynamically

```
<div class="info">

    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>

    <h1></h1>

</div>

<div class="info">

    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>

    <h1></h1>

</div>
```

My code:

```
$('.info .text h1:nth-child(1)').each(function(i, obj) {

        var x = $(this).text();

        $('.info span.imgTitle').append(x)


});
```

How can i do to get the first of each h1 class " info " and make a append to another div ?

The problem is not show the info that i want. It show alls h1 in each append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ':first' which grabs just the first instance, rather than the first child:

`$('.info').find('h1:first')`